# Error when preparing a multiple insert query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
// BUILD VALUES
$count = count($matches);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $values[] = '(?)';
}
// INSERT INTO DATABASE
$q = $this->dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO hashes (hash) VALUES " . implode(', ', $values) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash = hash");
$q->execute($matches);
```

The code above fails with the following error

**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**

Although when `count($matches) == count($values)` just before execute is called?

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried passing array_values($matches) instead?

Comment: Why `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash = hash`?  May as well do `INSERT IGNORE ...`.  Did you mean to do `UPDATE hash = VALUES(hash)`?

Comment: Did the `$values` array already contain something prior to the loop?  Also, why not prepare a single `INSERT INTO hashes (hash) VALUES (?)`  and execute it multiple times?

Comment: @eggyal I am inserting around 1000 values and doing a multiple insert is around 10 times faster :)

Comment: @Griff: Is that even true in the case of executing a prepared statement multiple times?  I've never benchmarked it myself, but had always understood the performance impact to be negligible...

Comment: @eggyal Well I would guess so making one query or 1000 I can almost gurantee that 1 would be faster.

Comment: I just ran into this and for anyone else who might have the same root cause, I'd like to explain why the solution proposed by @Ja͢ck works: PDO's execute, when given an argument, will bind the values in the argument array on its own. If the argument is a numeric array, this will only work with ? placeholders, but if it's an associative array, it will only work with named placeholders because PDO uses the array's keys to bind the parameters. In the example, ? placeholders are used, and array_values($matches) will rebase the array into a numeric array, removing any string keys.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This error you are receiving is because the number of elements in `$values` & `$matches` does not match.

If `$values` & `$matches` do not contain the same number of elements then the insert will fail, due to the query expecting X params but it is receiving Y data `$matches`. In your case, `$values` probably already contains some values, which is the reason for the count mismatch. To avoid that, you must always initialize an array before the loop.

I believe you will also need to ensure the column hash has a unique index on it as well.

```
$matches = array('1');
$count = count($matches);
$values = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $values[] = '(?)';
}

// INSERT INTO DATABASE
$sql = "INSERT INTO hashes (hash) VALUES " . implode(', ', $values) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=values(hash)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$data = $stmt->execute($matches);
```

Comment: Great answer, I just ran into this, because i defined two columns with the same identifier - `:example`, that should also be a point to check for!

Comment: Just to Add, it might be because the parameter that you are trying to bind simply does not exists...

Comment: @Darren - You are my live saver. In my bindParam call that was executed in a foreach loop I had forgotten to include the keyfrom teh array index so I got bindParam(':id', 'someValue'), bindParam(':id', 'someValue2'),... instead of bindParam(':id0', 'someValue'), bindParam(':id1', 'someValue'),... Hope this helps someone to solve his mistery

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's intent. He was imploding `$count` times `(?)` -and not just `?`- with `,` because something like `INSERT INTO hashes(hash) VALUES('What'),('Terrible'),('Failure');` would work in SQL to make 3 row insertions in one statement. Your answer suggest something like `INSERT INTO hashes(hash) VALUES('What', 'Terrible' , 'Failure');` -referencing one column and give 3 values for a row! That would throw `Column count doesn't match value count` error- **How could this get +45 upvotes and OP's approval?** (Of course: "You will need to adapt it a little." you said...)

Comment: @SebasSBM this was exactly my thought. I editied it out, to make it at least sensible. Going into my collection of Stack Overflow WTFs. SO voting is *such* a mystery.

Answer (score 10):

> **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**

Unfortunately this error is not descriptive for a range of different problems related to the same issue - a binding error.  It also does not specify where the error is, and so your problem is not necessarily in the execution, but the sql statement that was already 'prepared'.

These are the possible errors and their solutions:

1. There is a parameter mismatch - the number of fields does not match the parameters that have been bound.  Watch out for arrays in arrays. To double check - use *var_dump($var)*.  "*print_r*" doesn't necessarily show you if the index in an array is another array (if the array has one value in it), whereas *var_dump* will.
2. You have tried to bind using the same binding value, for example: ":hash" and ":hash".  Every index has to be unique, even if logically it makes sense to use the same for two different parts, even if it's the same value. (it's similar to a constant but more like a placeholder)
3. If you're binding more than one value in a statement (as is often the case with an "INSERT"), you need to bindParam and then bindValue to the parameters. The process here is to bind the parameters to the fields, and then bind the values to the parameters.

   ```
    // Code snippet
    $column_names = array();
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$i, $column_names[$i], $param_type);
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$i, $values[$i], $param_type);
    $i++;
    //.....
   ```
4. When you're inconsistent in using The backtick to delimit literals that represent identifiers (not strings). (Using ``), but once you use them you have to be consistent for that query, i.e. you can't use backticks for one identifier and not use them for another, all have to have backticks if you use them. (e.g. SELECT `id` FROM `my_table`)
   Do not use back-ticks for placeholders
5. Any value in '' single quotes is always treated as a string literal and will not be read as a column/table name or placeholder to bind to.

Comment: Thanks for having reason #2, got be flabbergasted till I found this here.

Comment: And your initial version was also wrong. You **cannot** bind values to [column_names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/285587)

Comment: In case you think you can do something like this WHERE ` :column ` =1 , [it won't work](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/66f82f2dafba85f84542f3b250543de6/). Notice the double '' in the error message around id. PDO adds quotes to values, making the filed name literally `'id'`. Which means you cannot use placeholders for column names. Backticks have absolutely nothing to do with placeholders and cannot be used with placeholders in any way, either as a part of the name or surrounding. Please don't spread misleading information.

Comment: Dunno where did you get it but [you can use backticks inconsistently, wherever you want](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/34c043edbd1bd3af0196afbdb41e28bd/) even for one single column name.  Besides, all this backtick business has absolutely nothing to do with **question you are trying to answer**. The question is about placeholders, not backticks.

Comment: And I just noticed, #3 also makes no sense. As we learned already, no column name can be bound, so it's hard to tell what are you talking about. Let alone there is no such problem that can be solved by interlacing bindParam and bindValue. You can use either or both. And neither would cause the invalid parameter number error. The entire "to bind the parameters to the fields, and then bind the values to the parameters" statement is a crystal clear nonsense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense While I do value your input, I find your approach condascending.  I'm here to learn, and I don't claim to be *the* standard repository of all knowledge and wisdom.  I feel that labelling everything I write as nonsense is counter productive to the purpose of SO.  Having dealt with this error in various versions of PHP, I have found that using back ticks inconsistently with PDO and placeholders (i.e. using backticks where appropriate but nonetheless inconsistently) has resulted in this error.  Perhaps I'm wrong. Perhaps not. I'm speaking from my experience.

Comment: __6. There is a dash in a variable name__. 
E.g. column-a = :column-a Which may be set while the automated variable name is created according to the silly column name where dash is used.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after using the wrong parameter name when binding.

Notice **:tokenHash** in the `VALUES` clause of the query, but **:token_hash** when binding.

Fixing one or the other resolved the error.

```php
// Prepare DB connection
$sql = 'INSERT INTO rememberedlogins (token_hash,user_id,expires_at)
        VALUES (:tokenHash,:user_id,:expires_at)';
$db = static::getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// Bind values
$stmt->bindValue(':token_hash',$hashed_token,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score -1):

The same error I found will show if you have a mismatch of the column name in PHP & the database column name, Double check that too. This is what I had wrong.

Comment: in this case the error will be different, unknown column name

Answer (score -2):

I understand that the answer was useful however for some reason it does not work for me however I have moved the situation with the following code and it is perfect

```
    <?php

$codigoarticulo = $_POST['codigoarticulo'];
$nombrearticulo = $_POST['nombrearticulo'];
$seccion        = $_POST['seccion'];
$precio         = $_POST['precio'];
$fecha          = $_POST['fecha'];
$importado      = $_POST['importado'];
$paisdeorigen   = $_POST['paisdeorigen'];
try {

  $server = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=usuarios';
  $user   = 'root';
  $pass   = '';
  $base   = new PDO($server, $user, $pass);

  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $base->query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8',
                     character_set_client = 'utf8',
                     character_set_connection = 'utf8',
                     character_set_database = 'utf8',
                     character_set_server = 'utf8'");

  $base->exec("SET character_set_results = 'utf8',
                     character_set_client = 'utf8',
                     character_set_connection = 'utf8',
                     character_set_database = 'utf8',
                     character_set_server = 'utf8'");

  $sql = "
  INSERT INTO productos
  (CÓDIGOARTÍCULO, NOMBREARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAÍSDEORIGEN)
  VALUES
  (:c_art, :n_art, :sec, :pre, :fecha_art, :import, :p_orig)";
// SE ejecuta la consulta ben prepare
  $result = $base->prepare($sql);
//  se pasan por parametros aqui
  $result->bindParam(':c_art', $codigoarticulo);
  $result->bindParam(':n_art', $nombrearticulo);
  $result->bindParam(':sec', $seccion);
  $result->bindParam(':pre', $precio);
  $result->bindParam(':fecha_art', $fecha);
  $result->bindParam(':import', $importado);
  $result->bindParam(':p_orig', $paisdeorigen);
  $result->execute();
  echo 'Articulo agregado';
} catch (Exception $e) {

  echo 'Error';
  echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {

}

?>
```