# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number on laravel model query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So i have this query on my laravel model to be called in my controller

model:

```
public static function predikat($masa, $ipk_yudisium){

    $searchFilter = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 

m_predikat_yudisium.keterangan
FROM m_predikat_yudisium WHERE
m_predikat_yudisium.masa_awal_berlaku <= :masa and
m_predikat_yudisium.masa_akhir_berlaku >= :masa and
m_predikat_yudisium.range_awal_ipk <= :ipk_yudisium  and
m_predikat_yudisium.range_akhir_ipk >= :ipk_yudisium and
m_predikat_yudisium.group_id = 1"),
            array('masa' => $masa,
                'ipk_yudisium' => $ipk_yudisium
            )
        )
        ;
        foreach ($searchFilter as $predikat){
            return $predikat;
        }
        $predikat = (object) array('keterangan' => "" );
        return $predikat;
    }
```

controller :

```
$masa = $request->input('masa');
$ipk_yudisium= $request->input('ipk_yudisium');

$predikat = $data->predikat($masa, $ipk_yudisium); //$data is my model called name
```

but i cant execute that query, it got an error message saying :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: SELECT m_predikat_yudisium.keterangan
FROM m_predikat_yudisium WHERE
m_predikat_yudisium.masa_awal_berlaku <= :masa and
m_predikat_yudisium.masa_akhir_berlaku >= :masa and
m_predikat_yudisium.range_awal_ipk <= :ipk_yudisium and
m_predikat_yudisium.range_akhir_ipk >= :ipk_yudisium and
m_predikat_yudisium.group_id = 1)
```

what is wrong? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966251/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined)

Comment: Chances are you can't re-use placeholder labels.

Comment: use sprintf instead.

$data = DB::select(DB::raw(sprintf("select * from %s", 'table_name')));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use the same parameter name more than once, so try something like this

```
$searchFilter = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 
                        m_predikat_yudisium.keterangan
                        FROM m_predikat_yudisium 
                        WHERE
                        m_predikat_yudisium.masa_awal_berlaku <= :masa and
                        m_predikat_yudisium.masa_akhir_berlaku >= :masa1 and
                        m_predikat_yudisium.range_awal_ipk <= :ipk_yudisium  and
                        m_predikat_yudisium.range_akhir_ipk >= :ipk_yudisium1 and
                        m_predikat_yudisium.group_id = 1"),
    array('masa' => $masa,
          'masa1' => $masa,
          'ipk_yudisium' => $ipk_yudisium,
          'ipk_yudisium1' => $ipk_yudisium
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm still recieving the same error "Invalid parameter number" i'm using laravel 8, any thoughs?