# Secure SQL update in PHP

Tags: postgresql, html, php

As part of a job I want to update a database using a form. Since the database is large and is used by many users, I hope that this manipulation is at least secure for more safety.

HTML script :

```
<form action="http://localhost/modifier_infos_signaletique.php" method=POST >
    <div class="id_sign">
    <h5>Id "Signalétique" :</h5>
    <input type="text" name="id_sign" id="id_sign"/><br>
    </div>
    <h5>Infos "Signalétique" : </h5>
    <input class="comment" type="text" id="maj_infos" name="maj_infos" required maxlength='140'/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
    $user = 'xxxx'; 
    $pass = 'xxxx';

    try{
        $dbconn = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=xxxx',$user, $pass);
        $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $maj = $_POST['maj_infos'];
        $id = $_POST['id_sign'];

        $query = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE signaletique SET infos = ':infos' WHERE id = ':id'");
        $query->bindParam(':infos', $maj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        echo 'Données mises à jour';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Erreur : " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

However, when I use this script this error appears:

**Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :infos **

The error would be due to the parameter used for the bindParam function.
However, I have in the properties of my PostgreSQL database, info in "character varying". I tried to change this parameter to "text", but the error remains the same.

Forgive me for this question but I am new to PHP and my SQL skills are thin since I use pgAdmin and its tools a lot to build and interact with my databases.

Here is a screenshot of my database :

[image]

The info parameter is in "text" on the screenshot but basic this property was in "character varying" (140).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query string you put single quotes around your placeholders. This makes them strings, not placeholders. You do not need quotes when using placeholders.

This should work:
`$query = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE signaletique SET infos = :infos WHERE id = :id");`

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966251/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined for more information.